# ¿Cómo crear una lista de objetos en Python?

Tags: python

En Java el año pasado creé un pequeño sistema bancario en consola para un proyecto de la universidad.
Tenía ya los atributos para la cuenta en una clase Cuentas con sus respectivos getters y setters. En otra clase entonces, tenía un array estático para almacenar todas las nuevas cuentas creadas, tal que:

```java
public static Cuenta[] cuentas = new Cuenta[100];
```

Y tenía un método para enviar todos los datos a la nueva cuenta que se almacenaría dentro del array:

```java
public static Cuenta nuevaCuenta(int nC, String usuario, String contra, String nombre, float monto, int tipo, int deposito, int retiroM, int retiroC) {
    Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta();
    cuenta.setnC(nC);
    cuenta.setUsuario(usuario);
    cuenta.setContra(contra);
    cuenta.setNombre(nombre);
    cuenta.setMonto(monto);
    cuenta.setTipo(tipo);
    cuenta.setDeposito(deposito);
    cuenta.setRetiroM(retiroM);
    cuenta.setRetiroC(retiroC);
    return cuenta;
}
```

Y por ejemplo, si necesitaba consultar un saldo, lo hacía dependiendo de la posición de la cuenta en en array. Esa posición la almacenaba en una variable `num` cuando iniciara sesión con su cuenta para poder hacer todas las operaciones, por ejemplo:

```java
public static Cuenta consultaSaldo() {
    Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta();
    cuentas[num].getMonto();

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Su saldo actual en cuenta es: Q." + cuentas[num].getMonto());
    System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Presione cualquier numero para continuar: ");
    int opn = s.nextInt();
    if (opn >= 0) {
        menuCajero();
    }
    return cuenta;
}
```

Y si necesitaba crear una nueva cuenta, solicitaba todos los datos y las almacenaba así:

```java
cuentas[cnt] = nuevaCuenta(nC, usuario, contra, nombre, monto, tp, deposito, retiroC, retiroM);
```

Ahora estoy viendo Python y estoy tratando de adaptarme al cambio del lenguaje.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Cómo puedo crear un array (lista) de objetos Cuenta en Python y poder agregarlas a la lista?
De esa manera podría acceder a la posición de cada una de las cuentas para hacer validaciones.

Nota: En Python ya tengo mi constructor, al igual que getters y setters, ya solicito los datos y los almaceno en variables. Solamente me falta poder añadirlos a una lista.

**código en Python**:

```py
class Proveedor:
    def __init__(self, codProv, nitProv, nomProv, direcProv, telProv):
        self.codProv = codProv
        self.nitProv = nitProv
        self.nomProv = nomProv
        self.direcProv = direcProv
        self.telProv = telProv
        self.lstProv = []
    
    def registrarProveedor(self):
        self.lstProv += (self.codProv, self.nitProv, self.nomProv, self.direcProv, self.telProv)

    #---Codigo de proveedor---
    def getCodProv(self):
        return self.codProv
    
    def setCodProv(self, codProv):
        self.codProv = codProv

    #---NIT de proveedor---
    def getNitProv(self):
        return self.nitProv
    
    def setNitProv(self, nitProv):
        self.nitProv = nitProv

    #---Nombre de proveedor---
    def getNomProv(self):
        return self.nomProv
    
    def setNomProv(self, nomProv):
        self.nomProv = nomProv 

    #---Dirección de proveedor---
    def getDirProv(self):
        return self.dirProv
    
    def setDirProv(self, dirProv):
        self.dirProv = dirProv 

    #---Teléfono de proveedor---
    def getTelProv(self):
        return self.telProv
    
    def setDirProv(self, telProv):
        self.telProv = telProv
```

La clase en donde necesito agregar los nuevos objetos, y crear una lista es la siguiente:

```py
import msvcrt
import os
import clases.proveedor as registroP

class Registro():
    def registroProveedor(self):
        os.system("cls")
        print("----------------------------------------------")
        print("   --- REGISTRO DE NUEVOS PROVEEDORES ---")
        codProv = int(input("Código del proveedor: "))
        nitProv = int(input("NIT del proveedor: "))
        nomProv = input("Nombre del proveedor: ")
        direcProv = input("Dirección del proveedor: ")
        telProv = input("No. teléfono del proveedor: ")
```

Y así, siguiendo la lógica que traía desde el proyecto en java, podría validar datos según posición. Por ejemplo, que el código de proveedor no se repita al crear un objeto nuevo.

Comment: `[Cuenta(), Cuenta(),...]` Sería bueno que coloques el código de python para tener una idea de como lo haz implementado

Comment: podrias crear: global listaCuentasBancarias y asi agregar datos, recuerda que en python por defecto utilizas listas y no arreglos.

Comment: He añadido el código que tengo en Python, sólo que esta vez, en lugar de una cuenta bancaria, es un objeto proveedor.

Comment: @Spider-Man no creo que sea bueno usar variables globales, pues por ello existen los atributos de clase y de instancia